# How to set button icon size in material alert dialog

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, iconbutton

I have simple `MaterialAlertDialog` and i want to setIcon for postive button. So i set icon programmatically since i want unique icon for multiple alert dialog, and use same theme for all `dialog`

Here is how i done.

```
final MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(SubListActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
dialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete selected files ?");

ListView modeList = new ListView(SubListActivity.this);
modeList.setPadding(50,50,50,50);

CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(SubListActivity.this, temp);
modeList.setAdapter(adapter);
dialogBuilder.setView(modeList);

dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null);
dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete, (dialog, which) -> {

    //Some function
                    
}).setPositiveButtonIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_item_delete)).create().show();
```

Theme

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/primarySubText</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primarySubText</item>
</style>

<style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon">
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/secondaryLightColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkRed</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/darkRed</item>
    <item name="iconSize">4dp</item>
    <item name="iconPadding">4dp</item>
</style>
```

**result:**

[image]

If i set icon in theme the size fits button. But as i mentioned earlier i want to set unique icon for ever dialog.

So how do i adjust icon size ?

Comment: Did you consider to create custom dialog?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine without using custom dialog is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun showAlert(): AlertDialog {
  // for example we have drawable
  val drawable: Drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.positive)
  // our material dialog builder
  val alertDialogBuilder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(activity, R.style.AlertDialogStyle)
    /**
    then do something here, set title, body, etc..
    */
  // get alert dialog from builder
  val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()
  // for example, we add drawable to positive button
  alertDialog.setOnShowListener {
    // now we can get positive button from alertDialog
    val positiveButton = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
    // text size of our button
    val textSize = positiveButton.textSize.toInt()
    // drawable. we set size here
    val positiveDrawableResized = drawable.apply { setBounds(0, 0, textSize, textSize) }
    // add drawable to button
    positiveButton.setCompoundDrawables(positiveDrawableResized, null, null, null)
    // positive button click listener (if needed)
    positiveButton.setOnClickListener { alertDialog.dismiss() }
  }
  // finally, show dialog
  alertDialog.show()
  return alertDialog
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the size of the button icon in material dialogs is easy with styles.

You just have to override the 'alertDialogStyle' item like this:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/MyAlertDialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="buttonIconDimen">24dp</item>
</style>
```

(Note however that I'm using a different parent for 'AlertDialogTheme')